# Where is the Sonar "duplicated code" here?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I just run sonar scanner on the sample Sonar project. It gives me the message that there is "duplicated code on lines 7-20". Can anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: Code duplication is not just copy-pasted code, it's copy-pasted *logic*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

SonarQube is telling you that this portion of the code contains duplicated logic. This doesn't necessarily mean that the code itself is copy-pasted, but that, conceptually, the exact same thing is happening at multiple places. In this case, the logic of returning a `String` value with regard to the `int` value is clearly repeated.

A simple solution here:

```
String[] array = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };
if (i >= 1 && i <= array.length) {
    return array[i - 1];
}
```

Comment: I do not know how Sonar can detect "duplicated logic" but the solution looks the right one.

Comment: Literals are ignored in copy paste detection. So if you "blank" int literals and string literals... the code is duplicated.

Comment: so complexity is preffered over any duplication by sonar's detection?

Answer (score 2):

SonarRules for Java projects:

> A piece of code is considered as duplicated as soon as there is the
>   same sequence of 10 successive statements whatever the number of
>   tokens and lines. This threshold cannot be overridden.

You need to modify that multiple **if return** sections

Comment: I do not find more than 7. How did you count?